# problem with figure on a0poster

Tags: floats, posters

Iam trying to put a figure on my `a0poster`. But I get the error message: `LaTeX error: Float(s) lost`; and my figure is suppressed. I have subdivided my `a0poster` into regions using `minipages`. My figures are in `eps`-format. The figures get converted into `pdf` without problems. Could somebody give me a hint how to overcome my problem?

Comment: `figure` is a floating environment which doesn't really make sense on a poster, you can just include an image with `\includegraphics`

Answer (score 2):

- Do not use `\centerline` but `\centering`
- Do not use `\epsfig` but `\includegraphic` from `graphicx`
- Do not use floats on a poster as this does not make sense

  ```
  % arara: pdflatex

  \documentclass{a0poster}
  \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
  \usepackage{showframe} % for demo

  \begin{document}
  \noindent\fbox{% % for demo
  \begin{minipage}{50cm}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=20cm,height=10cm]{file=fig_pub/post_hk70_income01.eps}
  \end{minipage}
  } % for demo
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem myself: eliminate the figure(begin end) and just enclose
something like 

`\centerline{\epsfig{
file=fig_pub/post_hk70_income01.eps,
width=20cm,height=10cm}}`

The caption I do in the text.

Comment: don't use the plain tex `\centerline` in latex (it can place things oddly by trying to make a new paragraph); also, probably best not to use `\epsfig` (it comes from a reimplementation of an obsolete latex 2.09 package, and confuses old fogies like me :-} )